# How to deploy app for Windows Phone 8.1 from PC

Tags: deployment, automated-tests, windows-phone-8.1

I download an app (xap/appx) from Windows Phone Store (ex: clock-tile-diy.appx). I use Windows Phone Application Deployment (8.1) to deploy the app on my phone from pc. But it have error: A packaging error prevented this application from installing. Why do it have errors and How do I fix it?
Please help me.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: if I right, so cool to see a female developer :D
Cheers >;<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't deploy xap or appx packages you downloaded from the store as they are different from the ones that Visual Studio generates.

To install packages you downloaded from the store, simply put them on your SD card or the internal documents folder of your phone. Open store and look into the command bar, there should be an option allowing you to install the file.